# Can ASP's objConn.execute handle a SQL query that uses the subquery factoring with clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, asp-classic, with-clause, subquery-factoring

I have a long SQL statement that's essentially:

```
with a as (select * from t1),  
  b as (select * from a, t2 where a.id=t2.id)  
select * from b
```

This statement executes perfectly fine in my TOAD application. But, when I try to stuff the above into a string variable and run it in ASP using:

```
set rs = objConn.execute(strSQL)
```

I get the following error:
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e37'
[Microsoft][ODBC driver for Oracle][Oracle]ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
/Application/xxxxx/yyyyy/myfilename.asp, line 168

Line 168 is the set rs = objConn.execute(strSQL) line.

I've used these same tables to run several other queries and posting them online using the set rs = objConn.execute(strSQL) line with no problem. The only thing I can determine is different with this SQL query is the subquery factoring.

I tried wrapping the whole query up in it's own select statement like:

```
select * from (with a as blah blah... entire original query)
```

But that still throws the same error. Can I just not use set

```
rs = objConn.execute(strSQL)
```

in conjunction with subquery factoring? Is that not supported? Or is there some kind of work around? Or could it be something else entirely?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm stupid. Wrapping select * from () around the whole block does indeed work. My error was being thrown because I forgot I was trying to join into a table that was actually in a different schema that I wasn't connected to.

Comment: You should post this as your answer.

Comment: Ah, thanks, added. I'm not familiar with posting questions on Stack Overflow and didn't see the big "Add Answer" button.

Answer (score 1):

I'm stupid. Wrapping select * from () around the whole block does indeed work. My error was being thrown because I forgot I was trying to join into an old (rarely used anymore) table that was actually in a different schema that I wasn't connected to. I solved the problem by rewriting the query to pull some of the needed data from that obscure table to a different table that I was connected to and contained the same data I needed.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Driver is very old. It was created when Oracle 7 was around and has not really been updated since. The WITH clause was added with Oracle 9.2.

I am surprised your `select * from ()` workaround does not work. It is exactly what we are using and it is working fine for us.

Another solution is to use the `Oracle Provider for OLE DB` instead of the Microsoft driver. It is provided by Oracle and is updated with every Oracle release.

Comment: Ah, I was over-complicating it. Yes, the select * from () workaround does work. My table or view name not existing error was being thrown because one of the many tables I was trying to join from was in a different schema I wasn't connected to. I completely overlooked that this report actually does have a small join with a different table we don't usually use. Thanks.